# Evidential reasoning in Gaussian Bayesian Networks

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, bayesian-network

I am working on Gaussian Bayesian Networks (GBN) i.e. the Bayesian Networks where all the random variables are continuous in nature. I am seriously trapped in the problem of evidential reasoning in case of GBNs. Can anybody help me by guiding me regarding

1. whether there are any established algorithm for evidential reasoning or inference in case of GBNs?
2. if yes then please provide me some references
3. if no then can anybody suggest how should I proceed in inference using GBNs.
4. can I directly apply the inference algorithms of discrete variable Bayesian Networks in case of GBNs?
5. lastly, my objective is to deduce some algorithm for multiply connected GBNs. in most of the cases the inference algorithms are for singly connected Bayesian Networks. For multiply connected Bayesian Networks what will be the changes required in inference algorithms?